# sed replace all tabs and spaces with a single space

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bash, sed, dig

I got a string like the following:

```
test.de.          1547    IN      SOA     ns1.test.de. dnsmaster.test.de. 2012090701 900 1000 6000 600
```

now I want to replace all the tabs/spaces inbetween the records with just a single space so I can easily use it with `cut -d " "`

I tried the following:

```
sed "s/[\t[:space:]]+/[:space:]/g"
```

and various varions but couldn't get it working. Any ideas?

Comment: Try: sed -r -e "s/[\t\ ]+/ /g"

Comment: Does your `cut` supports `-w` option?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g"`

Here's an explanation:

```
[   # start of character class

  [:space:]  # The POSIX character class for whitespace characters. It's
             # functionally identical to [ \t\r\n\v\f] which matches a space,
             # tab, carriage return, newline, vertical tab, or form feed. See
             # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes

]   # end of character class

\+  # one or more of the previous item (anything matched in the brackets).
```

For your replacement, you only want to insert a space. `[:space:]` won't work there since that's an abbreviation for a character class and the regex engine wouldn't know what character to put there.

The `+` must be escaped in the regex because with sed's regex engine `+` is a normal character whereas `\+` is a metacharacter for 'one or more'. On page 86 of *Mastering Regular Expressions*, Jeffrey Friedl mentions in a footnote that ed and grep used escaped parentheses because "Ken Thompson felt regular expressions would be used to work primarily with C
code, where needing to match raw parentheses would be more common than backreferencing." I assume that he felt the same way about the plus sign, hence the need to escape it to use it as a metacharacter. It's easy to get tripped up by this.

In sed you'll need to escape `+`, `?`, `|`, `(`, and `)`. or use -r to use extended regex (then it looks like `sed -r -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g"` or `sed -re "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g"`

Comment: Does this remove tabs too? Can you explain why you use `\+` instead of just `+`?

Comment: Okay, I understand. [[:space:]] is equal to [ \t\r\n\v\f]. But can you please explain why you use `\+`

Comment: [[:space:]] is equivalent to '\s', so the shorter version is "s/\s\+/ /g"

Comment: Basic regular expressions use a backslash prior to a plus sign when used to mean “one or more of the previous character or group”, source https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/opensource/conceptual/shellscripting/RegularExpressionsUnfettered/RegularExpressionsUnfettered.html.

Comment: Ahh, I understand! I did not know that there were different regex versions. Thanks

Comment: This seems wrong. at least on OSX I have to do `sed -E "s/[[:space:]]+/ /g"

when we go to extended you dont need to escape the + sign for multiplicity anymore.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `-s` ("squeeze") option of `tr`:

```
$ tr -s '[:blank:]' <<< 'test.de.          1547    IN      SOA     ns1.test.de. dnsmaster.test.de. 2012090701 900 1000 6000 600'
test.de. 1547 IN SOA ns1.test.de. dnsmaster.test.de. 2012090701 900 1000 6000 600
```

The `[:blank:]` character class comprises both spaces and tabs.

Comment: Seems like the simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some interesting methods I found via experiments (using xxd to see tabs).

```
echo -e \\033c
s=$(echo -e "a\t\tb\t\tc\t\td\t\te\tf")

echo 'original string with tabs:'
echo "$s"
echo "$s" | xxd

echo -e '\nusing: \techo "$s" | tr -s \\\\t " "'
echo "$s" | tr -s \\t " "
echo "$s" | tr -s \\t " " | xxd

echo -e '\nusing: \techo "$s" | sed '"'s/\\\\t/ /g'"
echo "$s" | sed 's/\t\+/ /g'
echo "$s" | sed 's/\t\+/ /g' | xxd

echo -e '\nusing: \techo ${s/ / }'
echo ${s/ / }
echo ${s/ / } | xxd

z=$(echo $s)
echo -e '\nusing: \tz=$(echo $s); echo "$z"'
echo "$z"
echo "$z" | xxd

echo -e '\nusing: \tread s < file.in; echo $s'
read s < file.in
echo $s
echo $s | xxd

echo -e '\nusing: \twhile read s; do echo $s; done'
while read s;
do
  echo $s
done < file.in
```

Answer (score -2):

I like using the following alias for bash.
Building on what others wrote, use sed to search and replace multiple spaces with a single space.  This helps get consistent results from cut.  At the end, i run it through sed one more time to change space to tab so that it's easier to read.

```
alias ll='ls -lh | sed "s/ \+/ /g" | cut -f5,9 -d" " | sed "s/ /\t/g"'
```

Comment: How does this answers the question?